# How to configure HAProxy for same IP and port in tcp mode using 2 different backends?

Tags: nginx, haproxy, http2

I do have HAProxy configured with https termination using the http mode:

```
frontend apache-https
   #mode tcp
    bind 192.143.56.150:443 ssl crt /etc/ssl/private/rabbit.pem 

    option http-server-close                # needed for forwardfor
    option forwardfor                       # forward IP Address of client
    reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
    default_backend apache-http

    acl fx_static   hdr(host) -i static.rabbit.fx-com
    use_backend nginx-cluster       if fx_static
```

Now I do want to change the static. domain to http2. The problem is, that I would need to switch to tcp mode in order to do that and in the same time I would loose the ACL http-mode feature.

How is it possible to configure HAProxy for the same IP and port in tcp mode to use 2 different backends?

I would like to use this line together with tcp mode just for static.

```
   use_backend nginx-cluster-http2 if { ssl_fc_alpn -i h2 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution below eliminates the `http` mode and therefore the injection of *forward* headers in favor of using the PROXY protocol via the `send-proxy` directive. The backend server must be able to accept the PROXY protocol, and both Apache and Nginx supports it.

The host match is performed using SNI rather than the `Host` header.

A HTTP/2 request for the static domain will be forwarded to the HTTP/2 backend server, in the example listening on `127.0.0.1:8888`, where a clear-text HTTP/2 server must be listening.

All other requests will be forwarded to `127.0.0.1:9999` where a clear-text HTTP/1.1 server must be listening.

```
frontend fe
  mode tcp
  bind *:443 ssl no-sslv3 crt /etc/ssl/domain.pem
  acl static_domain req.ssl_sni -i static.domain.com
  acl http2 ssl_fc_alpn -i h2
  use_backend be_static if static_domain http2
  default_backend be_non_static

backend be_static 
  mode tcp
  server 127.0.0.1:8888 send-proxy

backend be_non_static
  mode tcp
  server 127.0.0.1:9999 send-proxy
```

If you really need to have the *forward* headers, for example because your application relies on them, you can use the solution below:

```
frontend fe
  mode tcp
  bind *:443 ssl no-sslv3 crt /etc/ssl/domain.pem
  acl static_domain req.ssl_sni -i static.domain.com
  acl http2 ssl_fc_alpn -i h2
  use_backend be_static if static_domain http2
  default_backend be_non_static

backend be_static 
  mode tcp
  server 127.0.0.1:8888 send-proxy

backend be_non_static
  mode tcp
  server 127.0.0.1:7777 send-proxy

frontend fe_non_static
  mode http
  bind 127.0.0.1:7777 accept-proxy
  option forwardfor
  reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
  default_backend be_other

backend be_other
  mode tcp
  server 127.0.0.1:9999
```

For this second solution the idea is that HTTP/2 static requests would work as before, while the other requests will first be directed to a private, "local", frontend listening on port 7777, working in `http` mode, where you can inject the *forward* headers.

From the private, "local", frontend you can forward to the backend server as before - only this time you don't need the `send-proxy` directive.

Given the wide support for the PROXY protocol by virtually any server, I would recommend to not use *forward* headers unless really necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Not sure if this solves the problem. To make the setup clear: on subdomain www. there is apache serving requests on static. there is NGINX serving requests. So the problem comes down to the point that I must be able to seperate the request in order to root to two different servers. Each of them could then afterwords be configured with virtualhosts directives. Maybe I also do not entirely understand your solution.

Comment: Your problem is to tell HAProxy to route based on the host name to Apache (HTTP/1.1) or Nginx (HTTP/2). You build the ACL with the `req.ssl_sni` directive for the host name selection and with the `ssl_fc_alpn` for protocol selection. Once you have separated the routes, the first solution should be straightforward to understand: static HTTP/1.1 goes to 9999, any HTTP/2 to 8888. The second solution is slightly more elaborated in case of _forward_ headers. A static HTTP/1.1 request would hit HAProxy, routed onto HAProxy again, but on port 7777, added the _forward_ headers and then sent to 9999.